# How to solve Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming, wordpress-plugin-creation

my website running perfect but today 1 order is placed by the customer, and I am getting this error in my website.

**Here is the screenshot of error**

[image]

error is here..
`Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Error saving action: Error saving action: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' in /home/website/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/packages/action-scheduler/classes/migration/ActionScheduler_DBStoreMigrator.php:44`

Comment: Which parts of that error message are unclear? What have you tried to resolve that problem?

Comment: main error in first part of the message

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to table structure and then hover on More option in front of id field and then click on primary key.
[Here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0ayz.png)

if problem still there after doing this then click on change in front of id field and check the A.I checkbox

[Here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u7Ww.png)

Comment: when I am activating `woocommerce` plugin, then I am getting those errors

Comment: Did you try the solution i mentioned above?

Comment: what i mentioned above, you have to do with all tables manually. Otherwise you can try to re-install wordpress. but before doing this, try once the solution i mentioned.

Comment: i tried but that's not working...getting same error

Comment: did you implement for all tables?

Comment: No, I implement only for 1 table, I am implementing this on all tables

Comment: I am getting this issue in one table...Please check the screenshot....
`https://prnt.sc/u5jqn7` and `log_id` is different here `https://prnt.sc/u5jrqe` and after some records `log_id` is `0` ..`https://prnt.sc/u5jsj7`

Comment: i think this table hasn't defined any primary key column. did your old issue resolved?

Comment: How many tables remaining haven't implemented the solution i mentioned above?

Comment: yes, I  implement but 2 table showing `Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: you have to make them same. each table should have primary key working with Auto Increament

Comment: This saved the day for me, in my case the ID was named action_id and when I checked the AI option, everything seems to be working well again

Answer (score 2):

Error resolved when I changed id=0 to id=1 in

```
actionscheduler_actions
```

table.