# WooCommerce : Fatal Error "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'" - No ID Field In Database

Tags: php, sql, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently experience issues with my WP WooCommerce site, the error given shows that the `wp_actionscheduler_actions` table is having an issue with the PRIMARY Key

I have dealt with these errors before, however usually the fix is just to set the PRIMARY key field (Usually ID) to auto-increment and the website works fine after that.

But now the error is with the PRIMARY key `action_id`. This column does not necessarily have fields that need to increment, and for some reason the row giving the error is `woocommerce_run_on_woocommerce_admin_update`. The only other rows in this table are rows for the "Facebook for WooCommerce" plugin. It is also the only row in the table to have the `group_id` "5", while all the other entries are set to "7".

I have recently moved hosting (Same hosting, just different account) and I am worried that they had messed with some of the data in the database for the website.

Below are some screenshots of the error message and database

***Error Message :***

[image]

***Table Rows***

[image]

***Table Structure***

[image]

***Action_ID Settings***

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63576290/how-to-solve-duplicate-entry-0-for-key-primary-in-wordpress)